# "Unfortunately, the package kvsetkeys could not be installed"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, miktex

I'm writing my degree thesis and I'm trying to write the bibliography. When I try to compile the installation of the "kvsetkeys" package is required, but the following error appears at the end of the process:

```
Unfortunately, the package kvsetkeys could not be installed.
Please check the log file:
C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
======================================================================
 (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty))

! LaTeX Error: File `logreq.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: pdflatex: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.

Latexmk: Missing input file 'logreq.sty' (or dependence on it) from following:
  ! LaTeX Error: File `logreq.sty' not found.
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'tesi.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'tesi.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'tesi.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'tesi.log' and/or above output for details

latexmk: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync.
```

I'm using Miktek and I also verified that the "kvsetkeys" package is already installed on it. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\input{introduction.tex}

\section{Come faccio i calcoli all'LHC}

MadGraph is an open source software written in Python, that aims at providing all the elements necessary for SM (Standard Model) and BSM (Beyond Standard Model) phenomenology, such as the computations of cross sections, the generation of hard events\footnote{Hard processes are those in which the momentum transfer is substantial with respect to the QCD scale.} and the automatical generating matrix element for High Energy Physics processes.

\section{Processi sensibili a $y_t$}

\section{Misura di 3+4 top semplificata}

\section{Unitarietà}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: install the logreq package with the miktex console.

Comment: Now it gives me a different errors. Anyway it says always that the package could not be installed :/

Comment: Can we infer from your new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/698342/35864 that you managed to install all required packages? Do you think it would be useful to type up and accept a quick answer of your own here, or do you think it would be more useful for other people to link to the generic MikTeX advice https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864 (i.e. update in both Admin and User mode thoroughly, then try to install)?=