# "Empty bibliography."

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm trying to write the bibliography of my bachelor's degree thesis using the biblatex package, but when I compile my .tex file a warning says "Empty bibliography." and nothing appear on the output pdf.

This is my main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

%bibliografia (aggiornata)
%das ferbel
%quantum field theory for gifted amateaur
%articolo higgs mechanism
%prima pagina madgraph
%documentazione madgraph

\section{Introduction}

\input{introduction.tex}

\section{Come faccio i calcoli all'LHC}

\section{Processi sensibili a $y_t$}

\section{Misura di 3+4 top semplificata}

\section{Unitarietà}

\newpage

\section*{Bibliography}

%\input{bibliography.tex}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is my .bib file, as you can see it s not empty as the compiler says:

```
@article{wombat2016,
    author   = {Walther Wombat and Klaus Koala},
    title    = {The true meaning of 42},
    journal  = {Journal of modern skepticism},
    date     = {201},
    keywords = {trusted},
}
@book{lion2010,
    author       = {Laura Lion and Gabrielle Giraffe and Carl Capybara},
    title        = {The dangers of asking the wrong question},
    publisher    = {publishing house},
    date         = {2010},
    keywords     = {trusted},
}
@online{wikibook,
    title        = {Generating Bibliographies with biblatex and biber},
    organization = {Wikibooks},
    date         = {2016},
    urldate      = {2016-03-07},
    url          = {https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Generating_Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber},
    keywords     = {untrusted},
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Edoardo

Comment: you need to run pdflatex, then biber to generate the bibliography, then pdflatex twice more. Latex never reads the bib file, it is the generated bibliography from biber that latex says is empty.

Comment: only entries that you `\cite` will appear, your example code shown has no `\cite`

Comment: You can also add `\nocite{*}` to tell tex to include every bibliographic entry whether or not it was cited.

Comment: Now it appears, thank you very much!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 might also be relevant reads.